# share video through mms intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I know its an old questions but i just cannot find the right answer. I want to share my video Via MMS, but i keep on getting this error "Unable to attach. File Not supported".

Following is my Code First is my Recording class and second one is the video Player:

```
public class VideoComponent extends Activity  {
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    public MediaRecorder mrec = new MediaRecorder();
    private Button startRecording = null;
    private Button stopRecording = null;
    private Button play = null;
    private Button gallery = null;
    int BytesPerElement = 2;

    File video;
    private Camera mCamera;
    File audiofile = null;
    boolean recording=false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);

        startRecording = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonstart);
        stopRecording = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share);
        play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        gallery= (Button)findViewById(R.id.gallery);


        mCamera = Camera.open();
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);


        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();


        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        startRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if(recording==false)
                        startRecording();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i("test" , "Video Not starting");

                }

            }
        });
        stopRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                    recording=false;
                    stopRecording();

            }
        });
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),VideoPlayer.class);
                i.putExtra("URI", audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Gallery.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
          Log.i("Test" , "Menu thing");
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "StartRecording");
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "StopRecording");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case 0:
            try {
                  Log.i("Test" , "Start Recording");
                startRecording();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String message = e.getMessage();
                Log.i("Self", "Problem Start"+message);
                mrec.release();
            }
            break;

        case 1: //GoToAllNotes
            mrec.stop();
            mrec.release();
            mrec = null;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void startRecording() throws IOException 
    {
        recording=true;
        String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File sampleDir = new File(path+"/DCIM/Camera");
        sampleDir.mkdir();


         Log.i("Setting Path", sampleDir.toString());

            try {
              audiofile = File.createTempFile("Video", ".3gp", sampleDir);
            } catch (IOException e) {

              return;}
            int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000, 
                 AudioFormat .CHANNEL_IN_MONO, 
                 AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        mrec = new MediaRecorder();  // Works well

        mCamera.unlock();
        mrec.setCamera(mCamera);

        mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mrec.setMaxDuration(60000);
        mrec.setAudioSamplingRate(16000);
        mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        mrec.setPreviewDisplay( surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mrec.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath()); 
        mrec.prepare();
        mrec.start();


    }

    protected void stopRecording() {
        mrec.stop();
        mrec.release();
        mCamera.lock();
        mCamera.release();
        Log.i("testing","going to call Destroyer");
        //surfaceDestroyed(surfaceHolder);

        //mCamera.stopPreview();


         //finish();
    }

   private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
       Log.i("testing","re;ease Media record"); 
       if (mrec != null) {
            mrec.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
            mrec.release(); // release the recorder object
            mrec = null;
            mCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera(){
           Log.i("testing","re;ease Camera");
        if (mCamera != null){
            mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my Video Player class

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity {
VideoView videoView;
Button mms=null;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    //Create a VideoView widget in the layout file
    //use setContentView method to set content of the activity to the layout file which contains videoView
    this.setContentView(R.layout.video);
    final Intent i= getIntent();
    final String uri=i.getStringExtra("URI");
    Log.i("URI","Path is"+Uri.parse(uri));

    mms=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mms);

    videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

    //add controls to a MediaPlayer like play, pause.
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);

    //Set the path of Video or URI
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));

  //Set the focus
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();


    mms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
             i.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse(uri));
            i.setType("video/*");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Manifest File

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.videoplayer"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".VideoComponent"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity android:name=".VideoPlayer"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:mimeType="*/*"  />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".VideoRecorder"
              android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Gallery"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

EDIT: File Format is .3gp. Not Problem with path since it is working for Email. 
EDIT # 2: Complete code is attached please check if there is some problem in passing uri of  the video correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try like below intent

```
            ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            for (int i = 0; i < checkeditem.size(); i++) {
                File file = new File(RecordService.DEFAULT_STORAGE_LOCATION,checkeditem.get(i).toString());
                Log.i("Share Media ","Sending is file is " + file.toString());
                imageUris.add(Uri.fromFile(file));
            }
            // (3) to share multiple file in URi use below code here
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUris);
            shareIntent.setType("*/*");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with"));
```

Comment: Its not working and giving the same result. Although when i try to share it directly from gallery message or Facebook its working fine. so it means there is some problem in my code.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
               i.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
               i.putExtra("Hi ", "Please find attachment"); 
               i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
               i.setType("video/*");
              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share via"));
```

let me know your status.

Comment: Its not working and giving the same result. Although when i try to share it directly from gallery message or Facebook its working fine. so it means there is some problem in my code.

Comment: this code will connect to native applications of facebook or anything. i think the fault is your mobile mms.

Comment: mobile mms is fine because when i try to share it directly from gallery, it is working fine. Even when i manually open Messaging App of android phone and attache this video to make it mms it works fine. Kindly check this code. or suggest there can be problem in some other place.